# Thymeleaf spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security, thymeleaf

I have been trying to check if the current user has any specific role with the thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity

```
<dependencies>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
  <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

In the servletcontext.xml

```
<bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
      <property name="additionalDialects">
        <set>
          <bean class="org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity3.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect"/>
        </set>
      </property>
    </bean>
```

In my view, I have been trying to

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<body>
  <!-- Template page showcasing C-EASY graphic elements -->
  <div th:fragment="content">
    home
    <div sec:authorize="hasAuthority('ROLE_PORTEFEUILLE')">Show ROLE_PORTEFEUILLE</div>
    <div sec:authorize="hasAuthority('ROLE_BOITEAOUTIL')">Show ROLE_BOITEAOUTIL.</div>

    <div sec:authorize="hasAuthority('ROLE_SIMULER')">Show ROLE_SIMULER</div>
    <div sec:authorize="hasAuthority('ROLE_SOUSCRIRE')">ShowROLE_SOUSCRIRE.</div>


     <div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMINTESTING')">
        This will only be displayed if authenticated user has role ROLE_ADMIN.
    </div>

    <div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">THis user is authenticated </div>

<div sec:authorize="isAnonymous()">This user is anonymous </div>

<div sec:authentication="name">
    The value of the "name" property of the authentication object should appear here.
</div> 

<div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
    This content is only shown to administrators.
</div>



  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The current user has all the roles except **ROLE_BOITEAOUTIL**.

```
home
Show ROLE_PORTEFEUILLE
Show ROLE_BOITEAOUTIL.
Show ROLE_SIMULER
ShowROLE_SOUSCRIRE.
Show ROLE_SIMULER_TEST
```

This will only be displayed if authenticated user has role ROLE_ADMIN.

```
THis user is authenticated
This user is anonymous
The value of the "name" property of the authentication object should appear here.
```

This content is only shown to administrators.

How can the user be authenticated and anonymous at the same time?
It seems for **hasRole(role)** returns true everytime.
What can be wrong and how can i debug this ?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your `<html>`:

```
xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3"
```

If that does not work, try using `hasAuthority('<somerole>')`

Comment: I used the xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5" and used the hasAuthority('role') in the html tag. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> It seems for hasRole(role) returns true everytime.

This is probably because you have forgotten about `sec` namespace in your template file.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags">
```

If in the output file you still see 'sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"' then have something wrong with your dialect configuration.

If no then you have to debug. The class responsible for those methods is

```
org.springframework.security.access.expression.SecurityExpressionRoot
```

which extends `SecurityExpressionOperations` interface

Just add a break point on whatever method you want to test and see why the result is like that.

```
boolean isAnonymous();
boolean isAuthenticated();
boolean isRememberMe();
boolean hasRole(String role);
boolean hasAnyRole(String... roles);
boolean hasAuthority(String authority);
...
and others
```

Comment: I added. Still returns true everytime